# Alexa Skill- Is the anyway to make the alexa skill configurable?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Is there anyway to make a configuration form for my skill?
I mean, I want to create an skill that consumes an api, that would be nice could change depending where the user hosts it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [account linking](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/account-linking-for-custom-skills.html) for requesting user input on a web form and instead of asking for username & password and approving those, you could ask for the API endpoint and approving that if you can access it.

If you do not want to store the endpoint on your backend side along with the userid and/or access token you create for authentication, you could use the endpoint as access token, so that amazon will sent it to you every time the user invokes your skill (but that is a kind of dirty hack).

Other options would be to create a webpage for entering the endpoint and create an intent for the skill, which will provide a pin-code (valid for x minutes and connected with the user id on your backend). You could also provide a QR code on Displays but at least you need to give the link in the description of the skill. If the user opens the page, he/she needs to enter the pin, then you now can conclude the userid and store the given endpoint with that. so every time Amazon sends you a request, you can look on your backend with the userid, which endpoint has been stored (or

Comment: did you ever saw any examples of that?

Comment: Yes, I used the account linking process on one of my skills to log into a third party backend which does not support oauth, so I need to store their user login credentials on my backend. But I encrypted it with a user individual generated random key and stored that one as the access token at Amazon, so without a request from there I can’t encrypt it - but it shows you can store any string there and on the page you can create any form.

Comment: The pin variant I have also implemented in a skill of mine and I saw a lot of other skills, which do not want to handle accounts and login, but need to store user data. I also did one skill, which generates a QR code, which included the Alexa User Id as URL parameter, so you even do not need to handle pin sessions… but it limits the voice only usecases and depends on a screen and a smartphone (not a PC, or Mac…)